# Click Back, Go to Main Page, Removed Questions are Grayed-Out, But Not Removed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome, homepage, back-button

Using Chrome, Windows XP:

Go to StackOverflow.com, click a question to view it, click back button to go back to StackOverflow.com.

My irrelevant questions are grayed out, but they are not removed.

**UPDATE:**  I just reproduced it by clicking on my own question, voting for it (getting the message that said I couldn't), then clicking back.

**FOUND IT:** Close all your open tabs/windows of StackOverflow.com.  Open a new tab, go to StackOverflow.com, click a question, click back, and there it is.  It even does it when I am on StackOverflow.com, go back to my speed-dial page, click on StackOverflow, click question, click back.

It seems once you have been on the site a while, this no longer happens, but when you initially hit the site, this occurs (for me) 100% of the time.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: 5.0.375.126 ... says it is up to date

Comment: so did you guys fix this?  or did Chrome change something?  It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

We can't reproduce this.

Comment: I just had it happen again twice this morning.  I can get a screenshot of it ... anything else I can send to help?